# how do I attach to my aspnet mvc website running in iisexpress vs 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I have a website running in aspnet mvc 4 website and I have detached the debugger and want to reattach, but I cannot locate the process I wish to attach to when I bring up the 'attach to process' dialog.

I am used to attaching to the webserver.exe (with port number) in vs2010 and was expecting it to be a similar experience in 2012 with IISExpress, but I do not see in the list of processes one that relates to my web site.

How does one achieve this in vs2012.

Comment: If you are using VS2012 i assume you are using Windows so there is a full featured IIS in your operating system so why not use that?

Comment: I am a creature of habit and have been running my websites whilst in development under Cassini. I could use IIS but I am familiar with visual studio wiring up my hosting environment for me and was hoping to let it continue to do so rather than having to set up an IIS site just for my development machine.

Comment: Interesting becouse since i've started using always a full IIS on my dev machine i would never use again IIS express. :)

Comment: Do you know if they is a way to attach to a website running in IISExpress? For me I have a preference for letting IISExpress run my site until I *need* full IIS. This little problem may become the reason I switch to using IIS again, but I would really like to know if attaching the debugger is possible or not before I go down that route because I am not so bothered how the web page is served as long as I can work with it in a way that is convenient to me.

Comment: And it is just as much for my curiosity that I need to know how to attach the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [AttachTo](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0265ab0-df51-4100-8e10-1f84403c4cd0) extension for Visual Studio 2010/2012.

Comment: +1 I was not able to attach the debugger to my web site before I added this extension, I can now attach to the process with this extension and by going to 'Attach to Process...' and selecting iisexpress.exe and attaching, very weird but thanks for pointing this extension out to me.